# Did I map the correct pin leads from web cam to usb cable for use on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: usb, camera

I have two Dell Latitude E5440 and I pulled out the camera for both of them. Although both the cameras look to have the same form factor, I do notice the inscription between them are different.  One camera has the label 12P2SF135 on the PCB board, and the other camera has the label CNFCH52_A1.  When I google these, the results are of cameras that all the same form factor and sellers claim it is for use for the Dell E5440.

The CNFCH52_A1 board left labels for each of the 8 pins that connect to the board via LVDS ribbon cable.  I see them in this order:

[image]

1. Diog_Loop
2. USB+
3. USB-
4. 3V3
5. M_CLK
6. M_GND
7. M_SIG
8. DGND

My goal is to convert this to a USB web cam that I can plug into a Raspberry Pi or another desktop computer.  I've found many blogs online that show how to do this. From what I understand, the USB cable will have four pin leads which are:

1. V+
2. Data +
3. Data -
4. Ground

It's not clear which web cam pins match up with which USB cable leads.  My guess would be:

- Web Cam 3V3 to the USB cable V+
- Web Cam USB+ to the USB cable Data +
- Web Cam USB- to the USB cable Data -
- Web Cam M_GND to the USB cable Ground

**So my question is, did I guess the correct mapping for these leads?**

---

Note: I could just test out my theory by hooking things up right now , but I worry about damaging the camera if my guesses are incorrect.   I'm also skeptical of whether I selected teh correct ground, because I noticed that Diog_Loop, M_GND and DGND form a short circuit when I tested with my multimeter.

---

And a follow up question....What is the distinction between Diog_Loop, M_GND and DGND?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both no and yes.

You correctly identified the data and supply pins, but they are not directly compatible.

The camera module expects a 3.3V supply.

USB VBUS supply is 5V.

If you just directly connect a 5V supply to a device that expects 3.3V, most likely you will damage something, either the camera module or the PC you connect it to.

It could be adapted with a 3.3V voltage regulator.

Comment: ok thanks, i added one more follow up quesiton in my post - wondering if you know what is the difference between Diog_loop, M_GND and DGND since my multimeter seems to say they are all ground?

Comment: Nope, but they might have a reason. If it is a diag_loop, it may tell the presence of the module being connected to the host, to use mic. Mic ground and digital ground could have been separate for noise reasons but was not kept separate for some reason.